# org-heading Properties Get/Set in org-babel Header

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I can get a property like this

```
:PROPERTIES:
:PRJ-DIR: ~/projects
:END:

#+begin_src shell :var x=(org-entry-get (point) "PRJ-DIR") :tangle no
echo Variable x has the value $x
#+end_src
```

, but can it be written to?;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `org-entry-put` to do that:

```org
* foo
:PROPERTIES:
:PRJ-DIR:  /tmp
:END:

#+begin_src shell :var x=(org-entry-get (point) "PRJ-DIR") :tangle no
echo Variable x has the value $x
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Variable x has the value ~/projects

#+begin_src elisp
(org-entry-put nil "PRJ-DIR" "/tmp")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
```

The value of `PRJ-DIR` is changed when you `C-c C-c` on the last source code block.

Note the similarities between `org-entry-get` and `org-entry-put` and do `C-h f org-entry-put` for more details.